# In Jupyter notebook: !which python and sys.executable return different paths

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Issue as in title.

I am trying to get Jupyter notebooks running python remotely on my work computer (far better resources than my personal machine).

I think the issue may be originating from how something in the environment is set up (Linux), but I have been troubleshooting for over a day now and could really do with some help.

I am using a virtual environment, and had some issues with getting it to use the jupyter executable in my virtual environment.  I have now resolved this.  I have installed the venv as a kernel and can run on this in the notebook (A) or I can launch the notebook explicitly using the venv executable (B).  However there is still an inconsistency between python paths of which and sys.executable:

In terminal (venv active):

```
(venv) npc8.pauln> which python 
/home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin/python
(venv) npc8.pauln> python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin/python'
```

Jupyter (identical in the cases of A and B described above):

```
! which python

/bin/python

import sys

sys.executable

'/home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin/python3'
```

As a sanity check, I replicated the above on my home machine - both return the same value, as I think would be expected.  I also noted that if I start a terminal from within the notebook, it does not enter the venv by default on my work machine, but it does on my home machine.

I also checked `jupyter-troubleshoot`, and include it incase it is useful:

Terminal (venv active):

```
(venv) npc8.pauln> jupyter-troubleshoot
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$PATH:
        /home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin
        /w/work3/home/pauln/TeXLive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux
        /mnt/share/cern_CentOS7/root/v6.20.04/bin
        ./
        /bin
        /usr/bin
        /usr/local/bin
        /home/pauln/apps/clas12root/bin
        /home/pauln/apps/chanser/bin

sys.path:
        /home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin
        /mnt/share/cern_CentOS7/root/v6.20.04/lib
        /home/pauln/wtf
        /usr/lib64/python36.zip
        /usr/lib64/python3.6
        /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload
        /home/pauln/wtf/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
        /home/pauln/wtf/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

sys.executable:
        /home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin/python

sys.version:
        3.6.8 (default, Apr  2 2020, 13:34:55) 
        [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]

platform.platform():
        Linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.8.2003-Core

which -a jupyter:
        /home/pauln/wtf/venv/bin/jupyter
        /usr/local/bin/jupyter

pip list:
        Package             Version
        ------------------- ---------
        argon2-cffi         20.1.0
        async-generator     1.10
        attrs               20.3.0
        awkward             0.14.0
        backcall            0.2.0
        bleach              3.2.1
        cachetools          4.1.1
        certifi             2020.11.8
        cffi                1.14.3
        cycler              0.10.0
        decorator           4.4.2
        defusedxml          0.6.0
        entrypoints         0.3
        importlib-metadata  2.0.0
        ipykernel           5.3.4
        ipython             7.16.1
        ipython-genutils    0.2.0
        ipywidgets          7.5.1
        jedi                0.17.2
        Jinja2              2.11.2
        jsonschema          3.2.0
        jupyter             1.0.0
        jupyter-client      6.1.7
        jupyter-console     6.2.0
        jupyter-core        4.6.3
        jupyterlab-pygments 0.1.2
        kiwisolver          1.3.1
        MarkupSafe          1.1.1
        matplotlib          3.3.2
        mistune             0.8.4
        nbclient            0.5.1
        nbconvert           6.0.7
        nbformat            5.0.8
        nest-asyncio        1.4.2
        notebook            6.1.5
        numpy               1.19.4
        packaging           20.4
        pandas              1.1.4
        pandocfilters       1.4.3
        parso               0.7.1
        pexpect             4.8.0
        pickleshare         0.7.5
        Pillow              8.0.1
        pip                 20.2.2
        prometheus-client   0.8.0
        prompt-toolkit      3.0.8
        ptyprocess          0.6.0
        pycparser           2.20
        Pygments            2.7.2
        pyparsing           2.4.7
        pyrsistent          0.17.3
        python-dateutil     2.8.1
        pytz                2020.4
        pyzmq               19.0.2
        qtconsole           4.7.7
        QtPy                1.9.0
        Send2Trash          1.5.0
        setuptools          49.6.0
        six                 1.15.0
        terminado           0.9.1
        testpath            0.4.4
        tornado             6.1
        traitlets           4.3.3
        uproot              3.13.0
        uproot-methods      0.8.0
        wcwidth             0.2.5
        webencodings        0.5.1
        wheel               0.35.1
        widgetsnbextension  3.5.1
        zipp                3.4.0
```

From notebook (again A and B):

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.3.1; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
$PATH:
    /mnt/share/cern_CentOS7/root/v6.20.04/bin
    ./
    /bin
    /usr/bin
    /usr/local/bin
    /home/pauln/apps/clas12root/bin
    /home/pauln/apps/chanser/bin
    /w/work3/home/pauln/TeXLive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux

sys.path:
    /mnt/share/local_CentOS7/bin
    /mnt/share/cern_CentOS7/root/v6.20.04/lib
    /home/pauln/wtf
    /usr/local/lib/python37.zip
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

sys.executable:
    /usr/local/bin/python3.7

sys.version:
    3.7.0 (default, Sep 17 2018, 10:25:45) 
    [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)]

platform.platform():
    Linux-3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-centos-7.8.2003-Core

which -a jupyter:
    /usr/local/bin/jupyter

pip list:
    Package            Version 
    ------------------ --------
    attrs              19.3.0  
    backcall           0.1.0   
    bleach             3.1.0   
    corner             2.0.1   
    cycler             0.10.0  
    Cython             0.29.6  
    decorator          4.4.1   
    defusedxml         0.6.0   
    emcee              2.2.1   
    entrypoints        0.3     
    importlib-metadata 0.23    
    ipykernel          5.1.3   
    ipython            7.9.0   
    ipython-genutils   0.2.0   
    ipywidgets         7.5.1   
    jedi               0.15.1  
    Jinja2             2.10.3  
    jsonschema         3.1.1   
    jupyter            1.0.0   
    jupyter-client     5.3.4   
    jupyter-console    6.0.0   
    jupyter-core       4.6.1   
    kiwisolver         1.0.1   
    MarkupSafe         1.1.1   
    matplotlib         3.0.3   
    mistune            0.8.4   
    more-itertools     7.2.0   
    nbconvert          5.6.1   
    nbformat           4.4.0   
    notebook           6.0.2   
    numpy              1.17.4  
    pandas             0.25.3  
    pandocfilters      1.4.2   
    parso              0.5.1   
    pexpect            4.7.0   
    pickleshare        0.7.5   
    pip                19.3.1  
    prometheus-client  0.7.1   
    prompt-toolkit     2.0.10  
    ptyprocess         0.6.0   
    Pygments           2.4.2   
    pymc               2.3.6   
    pyparsing          2.3.1   
    pyrsistent         0.15.5  
    pystan             2.18.1.0
    python-dateutil    2.8.1   
    pytz               2019.3  
    pyzmq              18.1.0  
    qtconsole          4.4.3   
    root-numpy         4.8.0   
    root-pandas        0.7.0   
    Send2Trash         1.5.0   
    setuptools         41.6.0  
    six                1.13.0  
    terminado          0.8.2   
    testpath           0.4.4   
    tornado            6.0.3   
    traitlets          4.3.3   
    wcwidth            0.1.7   
    webencodings       0.5.1   
    widgetsnbextension 3.5.1   
    zipp               0.6.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Hi, try the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373063/sys-path-and-sys-executable-is-incorrect-in-jupyter-but-no-applied-fix-is-worki/65798637#65798637)